# My fileExistsAtPath statement returns false when it should be true

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager, file-exists

I'm retrieving the receipt on my users device using the following code:

```
let receiptUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL
```

I then check to see what the value of receiptURL is by using:

```
print("receiptUrl is \(receiptUrl)")
```

My console displays the location as:

```
receiptUrl is Optional(file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/018CF51F-1F55-465B-AA98-B4AD5A864E06/StoreKit/sandboxReceipt)
```

I then use an if statement:

```
if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(receiptUrl!.path!)
    { //do great security stuff
    }
```

However, my fileExistsAtPath always returns as false. Very frustrating.

Comment: NO matter what I try it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

It's right result may be. appStoreReceiptURL doesn't show exist path. Just show store receipt folder will be there. this answer relative with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27544351/how-to-use-appstorereceipturl)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jay. I had a look but still cannot get the above to evaluate to true even though there seems to be a file. I think it may be a file permissions problem. It's as if I don't have the right permissions to open that particular folder but I need to retrieve the receipt to validate.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591415/appstorereceipturl-error) should be answer for your question.